# Comment lire ou énoncer la désignation d'une matrice, par exemple une matrice de 1x1

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques

Comment nommer une matrice 1x1 ? Une matrice de dimension 1 fois 1 ?

[image: une matrice]

Comment: La question n'est pas très claire, comme on utilise rarement des matrices de ces dimension : est-ce qu'il s'agit de savoir comment on nomme une matrice de dimension (1, 1) *précisément* ou est-ce que c'est un exemple particulièrement mal choisi pour demander comment on lit les dimensions d'une matrice (n, m) en général ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- matrice (de dimension) 1 par 1, A, d'unique élément 6
- matrice A de dimension 1 par 1

« Élément » n'est pas le terme utilisé spécialement pour les nombres dans les rangées d'une matrice ; le nom de ces nombres est d'habitude  « coefficient » ; on trouve aussi « terme » et « entrée ».

On trouve « élément » en tant que terme général, mais c'est un terme qui est spécialisé aux ensembles ([réf.](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmer_en_R/Manipuler_les_matrices)).

En vérité selon la théorie des matrices, lesquelles sont des fonctions sur des produits cartésiens de segments des nombres naturels, les nombres dans une matrices peuvent être appelés ses *images* (qui a pour synonyme « *valeur* »), mais ce terme unificateur de la théorie des ensembles n'est pas souvent utilisé ; théoriquement, il est entièrement valide.

Answer (score 7):

**Moi je** dis :

- ***une matrice carrée de dimension un***

ou... quand j'ai la flemme :

- *Une matrice un un.*

---

Par ailleurs la première suggestion de LPH est rigoureusement fausse ("*Unique élément 6*") 6 n'est pas un élément, c'est la **valeur** de la matrice.

Comment: Vous avez raison, ce n'est pas un terme spécial pour les matrices, mais « valeur »  n'est pas moins général qu' « élément » ; terme spécialisés : coefficient, terme, entrée.

Comment: https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmer_en_R/Manipuler_les_matrices

Comment: À noter que "une matrice de dimension (1, 1)" (prononcé "un un") est également valide. C'est très certainement une question d'habitude, mais mes professeurs en prépa disaient systématiquement "une matrice m n", qui est finalement la lecture directe de "une matrice (m, n)" (puisqu'on ne prononce pas les parenthèses).

Comment: quand je veux me prendre la tête, j'appelle cela une matrice mais en règle générale, j'appelle cela un scalaire

Answer (score -1):

Je dirais "la matrice scalaire d'entrée 6".